# How can I fix a deprecated user in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, constructor, deprecation-warning

I get the following error message:

> User Deprecated: Passing configuration options directly to the
>   constructor is deprecated since Symfony 4.2, use the default context
>   instead.

This is the code Symfony is giving as trace for the problem:

```
$serializer = new Serializer(array(new DateTimeNormalizer('d.m.Y'), new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new JsonEncoder()));
```

But I do not understand how to use a default context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use directly the service.

```
class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    public function index(SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        // keep reading for usage examples
    }
}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-datetime-normalizer) you have to use it like this:

```php
-$serializer = new Serializer(array(new DateTimeNormalizer('d.m.Y'), new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new JsonEncoder()));
-$serializer->serialize($myObject, 'json')

+$serializer = new Serializer(array(new DateTimeNormalizer(), new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new JsonEncoder()));
+$serializer->serialize($myObject, 'json', [DateTimeNormalizer::FORMAT_KEY => 'd.m.Y'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the code that caused the deprecation (the constructor of the DateTimeNormalizer class):

```
public function __construct($defaultContext = [], \DateTimeZone $timezone = null)
{
    $this->defaultContext = [
        self::FORMAT_KEY => \DateTime::RFC3339,
        self::TIMEZONE_KEY => null,
    ];

    if (!\is_array($defaultContext)) {
        @trigger_error('Passing configuration options directly to the constructor is deprecated since Symfony 4.2, use the default context instead.', E_USER_DEPRECATED);

        $defaultContext = [self::FORMAT_KEY => (string) $defaultContext];
        $defaultContext[self::TIMEZONE_KEY] = $timezone;
    }

    $this->defaultContext = array_merge($this->defaultContext, $defaultContext);
}
```

So basically it comes down to changing the parameters passed to DateTimeNormalizer (in my case I had a CompilerPass that did set the parameter, but in the example below I will keep it generic):

```
new DateTimeNormalizer('d.m.Y'); // old, causing the deprecation notice

// new and NOT causing the deprecation notice
new DateTimeNormalizer([
    DateTimeNormalizer::FORMAT_KEY => 'd.m.Y'
]);
```