# how can i get only the date from a dateTime entity?

Tags: api, postman, symfony4

When i want to get the date of a column it shows me  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUU5G.png) .
here's my code for the entity that contains the dateTime attribute:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $dateEcheance;

public function getDateEcheance(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    $this->dateEcheance->format('d/m/Y');
    return $this->dateEcheance;
}

public function setDateEcheance(\DateTimeInterface $dateEcheance): self
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Tunis');
    $this->dateEcheance = $dateEcheance;

    return $this;
}
```

and this is my API:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/getContract", name="getContract", methods={"GET"})
*/
public function getContract(ContratRepository $contratRepo) 
{    
    $contrat= $contratRepo->findAll();

    $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
    $normalizers =[new ObjectNormalizer()];
    $serializer =new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
    $jsonContent =$serializer->serialize($contrat, 'json', ['circular_reference_handler' => function($object){
        return $object->getId();
    }]);

    $response = new Response($jsonContent);

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    return $response;
}
```

any help would be apprecaited:)

Comment: You are using the default normalizer. Have a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49717748#49780578) and the announcement of the [`DateTimeNormalizer`](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-datetime-normalizer) for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method "getDateEcheance" return a DateTime object and $this->dateEcheance->format('d/m/Y'); is not pertinent here.

Perhaps you need to create another method like that :

```
public function getDateEcheanceLibelle(): ?String
{
    if( isset($this->dateEcheance) )
        return $this->dateEcheance->format('d/m/Y');

    return '';
}
```